# Data Analysis - Manipulating Auction Data in Excel - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, data-analysis

I have a .csv file with the following data from eBay auctions:

auctionid - unique identifier of an auction

bidtime - the time (in days) that the bid was placed, from the start of the auction

bidder - eBay username of the bidder

I am trying to create new variables for how long any given bidder participated in a particular  auction (time of last bid - time of first bid) and for how many bids the bidder placed in that auction. In other words, I need help creating a VBA script that will loop through each of the auctions based on "auctionid" and then calculate these two variables if there are bidders in the auction who placed multiple bids.

I am so confused on how I could go about doing this, but I know that there has to be a way for it to be done. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Cant you open it in Excel and make a pivot table with auction id as Row label and add bidtime three times in the Values? Just drag bidtime three times into your pivot and define min for one, max for one and count for the last one.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Just a quick follow-up, how do I get the newly generated values from the pivot table (the max and mins of bidtime) back into the original worksheet?

Comment: You can't. You'd have to copy the pivot-table and paste it. If you want the Min, Max and Count in the original list, just create the formulas for that. CountIf() is pretty clear, and then you could crerate a formula that would behave like MaxIF() and another one like MinIf(). Have a look at this site where it is explained: [http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2011/07/27/finding-min-if-or-max-if-in-excel/](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2011/07/27/finding-min-if-or-max-if-in-excel/)